# Ruby: Float 1.INF# and float -1.#IND out of range of integer

Tags: ruby, integer

I have a script which returns

`float 1.INF# out of range of integer`

I don't know why. Debugging revealed that a division by 0 led to this similar strange error message:

`float -1.#IND out of range of integer`.

I tracked down the source of the error message to [ruby core numeric.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e732e0074e53e7ddbaf863197ec3775d7e9d4516/numeric.c#L2834).

My questions are:

1. Have both messages the same cause (division by zero)?
2. Can I get this error message in any other case?

Test script with potential division by zero:

```
first_value = 1000
second_value = 0
# zero value leads to NaN
( first_value / 100.0 ) / ( second_value / 100.0 )
```

The result is `float -1.#IND out of range of integer`.

irb shows NaN for these calculations:

- `(0 / 100.0) / 0`
- `(0 / 100.0) / 0.0`.

Comment: Please paste the exact error message into your question. Do not write it by hand. Use copy and paste and include in the whole error message from start to finish.

Comment: @Christian : Division by zero (on an Integer) would raise a `ZeroDivisionError`. Doing it as a float, would return a special value called _Infinity_.  Converting that to Integer, would raise a `FloatDomainError`. If your script returns the String you are getting, you will have to debug it to find where it comes from.

Comment: Do you use any native extensions? What's your Ruby version? What is happening here is some non-Ruby code tries to convert a Ruby `Float` to C's `long `which doesn't support infinite values or NaN. A backtrace would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a page where someone asked [Why are the return values of these doubles -1.#IND?](https://inneka.com/programming/cpp/why-are-the-return-values-of-these-doubles-1-ind-2/):

Relates to some c++ code. I have some extensions built on/for windows.

This might be the answer:

> Windows displays a NaN as  -1.#IND ("IND" for "indeterminate")
> while Linux displays NaN.

and

> if you get 1.#INF or inf, look for overflow or division by zero,
> if you get 1.#IND or nan, look for illegal operations

Whatever illegal operations mean in this context ...